# Discrete math: determining whether a relation is a function

Tags: functions, discrete-mathematics

In my book, they ask us to determine whether the following is a function:

$S \subseteq \mathbb{R} \times \mathbb{R}$ with $S = \{(a, b) \mid a + b = 10\}$

For previous problems like this, they gave us a relation of ordered pairs on a set, which I easily plugged into domain/codomain and mapped to each other to determine if it satisfied the definition of a function. For this question, I have no idea where to start.

I know it is saying that $S$ is a subset of $\mathbb{R} \times \mathbb{R}$ (not sure what $\mathbb{R} \times \mathbb{R}$ means here), and that $S =$ a set where $\{(a,b)~\text{such that}~a + b =10\}$. I'm not sure how to use this information.

Comment: Welcome to MathSE.  This [tutorial](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) explains how to typeset mathematics on this site.

Comment: Please, if you are satisfied with the answer below, accept it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$\mathbb R\times\mathbb R$ means the set of all ordered pairs $(a,b)$ such that $a$ and $b$ are in $\mathbb R$.

Recall that a function can be thought of as a set of ordered pairs (the first entry is the input, the second is the output). So, for example $\{(1,2), (2,5), (3,2)\}$ is indeed a function. On the other hand, $\{(1,2), (1,5), (3,2)\}$ is not, since $1$ gets mapped to both $2$ and $5$.

Now, our set (relation) is the set of all of ordered pairs that sum to $10$. Can find two ordered pairs $(a,b)$ and $(a,c)$ with $b\neq c$ such that $a+b=10$ and $a+c=10$? If so, you will have that $a$ maps to both $b$ and $c$, and $S$ would not be a function.

If you cannot think of two such ordered pairs, it may be the case that it is indeed a function. To show that it is, you would need to show that if $(a,b)$ and $(a,c)$ are in $S$, then $b=c$. Can you show that if $a+b=10$ and $a+c=10$ then $b=c$? If so, you have shown that $S$ is a function.

Comment: thank you so much!